# Correct EventHandler to tell me when notepad closed

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Process pr;
        pr = new Process();
        pr.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"notepad.exe");
        pr.Disposed += new EventHandler(YouClosedNotePad);
        pr.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void YouClosedNotePad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("thanks for closing notepad");
    }

}
```

When I close Notepad I don't get the message I was hoping to get - how do I amend so that closing notepad is returned to the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need two things - [enable raising events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx), and subscribing to [Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Process pr;
        pr = new Process();
        pr.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"notepad.exe");
        pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // first thing
        pr.Exited += pr_Exited; // second thing
        pr.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }

    static void pr_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exited");
    }
```

Comment: @whytheq Are you sure? It works one me. +1 for the right answer by the way.

Comment: Message definitely should be there. Have you enabled events?

Comment: ...so this is a little different than some other events I've played with as I need to switch on this process Property `EnableRaisingEvents `?

Comment: @whytheq `Disposed` event will be called when you will call `pr.Dispose()`, if you are asking about this

Comment: only thing I was missing was the `First Thing` in your syntax - the `Second Thing` is just a shortcut that you like?

Comment: intuitively it seems that when notepad has been closed then the process has exited and been _disposed_? but looks like disposed is something more than just closing the application?

Comment: @whytheq second thing is just event subscription (you don't need to write event handler type in C#). Disposing process frees native process handle, which stored in Process (btw it also unsubscribes from watching for exit).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event instead of Disposed:

```
pr.Exited += new EventHandler(YouClosedNotePad);
```

You also need to ensure that the [EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) property is set to true:

```
pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: @whytheq: Updated answer to include a flag that you were missing on the process.